# SVN to Git with History?

Tags: git, svn, history, svn2git

For years, we have used SVN for our repository, and we want to migrate to Git. 
In 2015 someone made a change in one of our repositories.
He made a separate folder in the repository (with an subfolder), on the same folder hierarchical level like `/trunk`, `/branch` and `/tags`. (see projectA)

```
svnroot/
|-- projectA
    |-- branches
    |-- tags
    |-- trunk
    |-- new folder
        |-- subfolder
            |-- branches
            |-- tags
            |-- trunk
|-- projectB
    |-- branches
    |-- tags
    |-- trunk
|-- projectC
    |-- branches
    |-- tags
    |-- trunk
```

He has moved some parts from `/trunk` and other folders to this new folder.
When I now look in the history of the new folder, I see only the history since the new folder was created, but the history of the moved projects in the new folder seems to be complete.
Did I need to fix it in SVN before migration, and if this is needed how can I fix this?
Or must I do something special on migration?

Comment: Is this a one-time migration and you only use Git thereafter, or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want with your history, either with integrating all SVN sub-repos in one Git repo, or splitting your projects from SVN to multiple independent Git repositories.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)